# Dynamic cursor to handle different conditions

Tags: oracle, dynamic, cursor

I have three different cursor created just to handle three different condition where:
1) To get actual date data
2) To get cumulative data
3) To get net data
Three cursor having same amount of parameters, how can we best combine three cursors into one? I could pass in different cp_tran_type to indicate what kind of data i need.

Example below:

```
CURSOR c_credit(cp_object_id VARCHAR2, cp_date DATE, cp_tran_type VARCHAR2) IS
SELECT nvl(SUM(qty), 0) qty
FROM x
WHERE object_id = cp_object_id
AND **daytime = cp_date**
AND text_1 = cp_tran_type;

CURSOR c_cum_credit(cp_lifting_account_id VARCHAR2, cp_date DATE, cp_tran_type VARCHAR2) IS
SELECT nvl(SUM(adj_qty2), 0) adj_qty
FROM x
WHERE object_id = cp_object_id
AND **daytime <= cp_date**
AND text_1 = cp_tran_type;

CURSOR c_net_credit(cp_lifting_account_id VARCHAR2, cp_date DATE, cp_tran_type VARCHAR2) IS
SELECT nvl(SUM(adj_qty2), 0) adj_qty
FROM x
WHERE object_id = cp_object_id
AND daytime <= cp_date
AND **(text_1 = 'A' OR text_1 = 'B');**
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NVL (
           SUM (
               CASE
                   WHEN daytime = cp_date
                    AND text_1 = cp_tran_type
                   THEN
                       qty
                   ELSE
                       0
               END
           )
         , 0
       )
           qty
     , NVL (
           SUM (
               CASE
                   WHEN daytime <= cp_date
                    AND text_1 = cp_tran_type
                   THEN
                       adj_qty2
                   ELSE
                       0
               END
           )
         , 0
       )
           adj_qty
     , NVL (
           SUM (
               CASE
                   WHEN daytime <= cp_date
                    AND (text_1 = 'A'
                      OR text_1 = 'B')
                   THEN
                       adj_qty2
                   ELSE
                       0
               END
           )
         , 0
       )
           adj_qty
  FROM x
 WHERE object_id = cp_object_id;
```